Does the "Take action if OS is compromised" policy only work if knox manage client is installed?
I was reading on the Knox platform enterprise documentation online and I came across a policy that takes an action upon OS tamper detection.
Also on another site (Knox manage 24.09 release notes) it just says that this option is recently introduced with the 24.09 update to the Knox manage client.
So my question here is, Does this policy only apply or take effect if Knox manage client is installed?, assuming someone managed somehow to tamper with the OS and bypass the factory reset protection, and managed to flash a custom firmware or something else, will the device get locked down without Knox manage client installed?
